# Unable to see the application created in devportal inside the carbon console>list service providers

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Unable to see the application created using developer portal in service provider list inside carbon console management `https://localhost:9443/carbon/application/list-service-providers.jsp?region=region1&item=list_service_providers_menu&loginStatus=true`

This happens when I am using keyclaok as IDP and configured "apim_devportal" application to use Federated Authentication type with keycloak IDP. Please refer to the below configuration

[image: apim_devportal configuration in carbon console of apim 4.0]

But if I do not use federated authentication then there will not be this problem. Please suggest how to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

The Service Providers related to Devportal applications are created and assigned to specific user accounts along with `Application/` roles.

Therefore, if you are using the `admin` credentials to access the `Carbon Management Console`, and some other user credentials to log in to the Devportal, perform the following

- Login to the Carbon Management console
- Navigate to `Users and Roles` > `List` > `Users` > click on `Assign Roles` option related to the user that you have use to log-in to the Carbon Management console
- Assign the `Application/` role that is related to the Application that you have registered from the Devportal. Usually, it follows the `Application/<Application-Name>` pattern
- Once assigned, save and update, and try listing the Service Providers

You will now see all the Service Providers with which the user has been assigned (with the respective Application roles).